# Dealing with zeros in a poisson regression

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, missing-data, quality-control

Our code goes through multiple stages of review. I wish to use the number of defects at an earlier stage of review as a "defect density" estimate for later stages.

It sometimes happens that code has zero defects in the early stage of review. This is causing me trouble since if $\lambda = 0$ then $P(k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}=0$ for all $k$.

R does indeed just throw an error in this case:

```
foo = 0:10
bar = 2 * foo
glm(bar ~ log(foo), family = poisson)
# fails because log(0) = -Inf
```

I could get around this in several ways:

- Ignore places with zeros (this would drop 1,486 of my 4,476 data points)
- Replace all the zeros with some number
- Add one to everything

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Producing inference for $\lambda$ when the count is zero is an [interesting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Asymptotic_normality) (see the part "Estimate on boundary"). I'd be inclined to take a Bayesian approach for this kind of application.

Comment: This question is based on an incorrect assertion.  When $\lambda=0$, $P(0) = \exp(0)(0)^0/0! = 1$, not $0$. The problem is the use of a *log link,* because $\log(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: @whuber: good point! Is there a way around this in R?

Comment: `R` (via `glm`) allows various link functions; you can even define your own.

Comment: Yes, intensity zero should not crash Poisson functions, but it doesn't solve your problem, because it still produces zero probability of defects, which is not a reasonable prediction by any measure

Answer (score 2):

Either (as mentioned in a comment by @Glen_b) use Bayesian methods, or some kind of *borrowing strength*, that is, analyzing multiple data sets with a common model, with some common parameters (that can be seen as a way of empirical bayes.) You say

> It sometimes happens that code has zero defects in the early stage of
>   review

The estimated (mle) parameter of zero leads to predictions of zero future errors, though one could make prediction intervals (of the form $[0, .)$) for number of future errors, in some model.  But borrowing strength by modeling multiple datasets together seems to me better. This is now a deveoped field, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_reliability_models  and   [this google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=gsb40&q=models%20for%20software%20errors&lookup=0&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian is a sensible approach. However, if you're frequentists the intensity is still not zero even if you didn't observe any events.

Suppose, your'e asked what is the probability of [Sun not rising tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem)? You've been on Earth for 40 years, and it has always risen. So, from frequentist point of view the intensity is 1 in 40 years, as [Laplace would suggest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem). Next year it will be 1 in 41 years and so on. Hence, you should set the intensity to 1 in whatever the scale is. For instance, if the scale is the lines of code, then $\lambda =\frac 1 {\text{lines of code}}$