# One- vs two-sided credible interval for Poisson process with all zero counts

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data, credible-interval

In a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427019/confidence-interval-for-mean-of-poisson-with-only-zero-counts#427943), I asked about a confidence interval for the estimate of the mean of 50 observations of a Poisson random variable, for which all 50 observations had a count of zero. In the comments to an answer to that question by whuber, it was pointed out that you shouldn't use a one-sided confidence interval *just because* you have all zero counts. If you used a two-sided interval in situations where you observed non-zero counts and one-sided intervals when you observed all zero counts, your confidence intervals would no longer have their nominal level of coverage.

In that question a simulation of coverage convinced my that that was a bad strategy.

My question here is how would a Bayesian argue one way or the other for one- vs two-sided credible intervals for the same situation with all zero counts.

Consider a prior distribution of $gamma(1, 0)$, with a Poisson likelihood, that results in a posterior distribution of $gamma(1, 50)$, for data consisting of 50 observations of zero counts.

**How would you argue against using a one-sided credible interval?**

Comment: How could such a prior result in a nonsingular posterior if it assigns 0 probability mass to every possible rate parameter in the support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting philosophical issues arise with very small Poisson rates. Also
with the choosing of appropriate prior distributions for Bayesian analysis
of low rates.

**Hypthetical particle.** Suppose I'm looking for evidence of a theoretically predicted, but never
observed G-particle. After 50 runs of my particle collider, I have seen
no traces of the kind G-particles should make. So in 50 runs I have seen
no evidence that G-particles exist.

According to your prior, I have two possible 95% credible intervals:
two-sided $(0.0005, 0.0738)$ and one-sided $[0, 0.0600)$ or "rate below 0.06."

```
qgamma(c(.025,.975),1,50)
[1] 0.0005063562 0.0737775891
qgamma(.95,1,50)
[1] 0.05991465
```

On what grounds would you defend the two-sided interval with its lower bound
$0.0005?$ Certainly, I have no *empirical* evidence for existence of G-particles,
so that implied possibility of a non-zero rate relies altogether on (perhaps unintended) 'information' from
my "noninformative" prior.

> You ask, "How would you argue against using a one-sided credible interval?"
> In this scenario, ***I*** would not make such an argument. But as always, you might find someone with a different opinion.

**Rare particle.** How is it different if I am trying to figure out if my collider is capable
of observing H-particles, which are *known to exist,* but to be very rare?
Then I might choose a prior that focuses on the characteristics of my collider.
The lower limit of a two-sided credible interval might be interpreted
as a lower limit of my ability to detect H-particles.